How to disable Alt + Tilda ( ` ) on Linux Mint?
Trying to disable Alt + Tilda (`) shortcut on Mint but it's not showing up anywhere under the keyboard shortcuts.
It's a separate function from Alt+Tab that displays the current window only, as opposed to displaying all windows.
I've gone through every option in keyboard shortcuts multiple times & can see everything else such as Alt + Tab but Alt + Tilda is nowhere to be seen.
SOLVED - The shortcut was down as Alt+Tilda as opposed to Alt+', which is what showed up when I set that shortcut myself.
"Cycle through open windows of the same application" for anyone else struggling with this.

For me, Tilda is ~

Incidentally, it's tilde in English.

Solved it the moment after posting this..
The keybind was listed as Alt+Tilda as opposed to Alt+` and I overlooked it

@Orksmash Can I answer my own question?
